# React: Infinite Loop when Updating Parent from Custom Form Validation Child Component

Tags: reactjs

**(CodeSandboxIO Snippet provided below)**

Suppose I have a component, `<MyValidator>`, placed under each input control, to display error text when the input is invalid. This component gets a `value=..` prop (what to check) and a `rules='required;dateformat;etc...'` prop, a semicolon-delimited list of validations. (These are functions, also defined in `MyValidator`, executed by name: JS allows the syntax `this[func]()` to manually invoke functions by name.)

This works, and my validator instantly shows/hides itself with the right message depending on value. But I also have the requirement to keep the Parent Form component updated about all validation statuses, so it can decide to block the **Submit** button if any of its controls are invalid. I decided to let the Parent Form have a map, `validatorId -> valid (true/false)`, which will be updated in a callback function passed to each Validator (i.e. Child->Parent communication: callbacks).

**Problem**: the following code gives an infinite loop. It works if I remove `this.props.callbackFromValidator(this.props.id, ..)` from each validation function. But in that case, I have no way to keep the Parent Form updated.

**Parent Form**

```
class TopForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
     this.state = {
         //... .. OTHER CONTROLS .. ...
         testDate: null // State var. for Date Input control
         //... .. OTHER CONTROLS .. ...
         formValidations: {} // Map of type validatorId -> valid, to update Form with statuses
     };
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      Enter date in MM/DD/YYYY format: 
      <input type="text" value={this.state.testDate} onChange={this.handleDateInputChange} ></input>
      <MyValidator id="v_daypicker" value={this.state.testDate} rules="required;dateformat;" 
                   callbackFromValidator={this.setFormValidation}></MyValidator>
  }

  // Date Input On-Change Handler to set State var.
  handleDateInputChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({testDate: e.target.value});
  };

  // Function passed as function prop to MyValidator Child Component.
  // Receives {id: valid} object
  setFormValidation = (validatorId, valid) => {
        
        // Set/update Form Validations Map with new value
        this.state.formValidations[validatorId] = valid;
        // Clone map for React's setState and call setState to update
        let newmap = {...this.state.formValidations};   
        this.setState({formValidations: newmap});
    }
```

**MyValidator**

```
class MyValidator extends Component {

// We make the decision what to display in render() based on calling specified functions by name

// Constructor
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

// Rule Functions
// --------------
required() {
    if (this.props.value == undefined || !this.props.value.length || !this.props.value.trim().length) {
        //this.props.callbackFromValidator(this.props.id, false); // THIS CAUSES INF. LOOP - Inform Parent of curr Validations status
        return 'This field is required';
    } else {
        //this.props.callbackFromValidator(this.props.id, true); // THIS CAUSES INF. LOOP - Inform Parent of curr Validations status
        return null;
    }
}

dateformat() {
    let datestr = this.props.value;
    if ( ! /^\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d$/.test(datestr) ) {
        //this.props.callbackFromValidator(this.props.id, false); // THIS CAUSES INF. LOOP - Inform Parent of curr Validations status
        return 'Date must be in MM/DD/YYYY format';
    } else {
        //this.props.callbackFromValidator(this.props.id, true); // THIS CAUSES INF. LOOP - Inform Parent of curr Validations status
        return null;
    }
}

render() {
    
    let toperror = '';
    
    // Evaluate rule set
    let rules = this.props.rules.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < rules.length; i++){
        if (rules[i].length) {
            // Execute function by name
            let result = this[rules[i]]();
            if (result != null && result.length) {
                toperror = result;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return (
        <div style={{"color":"red"}}>{toperror.length ? toperror : ''}</div>
    );
}
```

}

On any Validator's render, the Parent should keep an up-to-date Map of the current statuses for each validator, keyed by Id. In this example, the Map would have `v_daypicker -> true/false`. There is an infinite loop right now.

Snippet: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-hertz-bwkbv?file=/src/ParentForm.js

You can see that the validator correctly displays different messages ('Required' for 'Blank', 'Invalid Date' for non-MM/DD/YYYY). You can also enter a valid MM/DD/YYYY and see it disappear. But when I click the Submit button, the ParentForm should tell me the current status, which in this example is as follows: e.g. `v_daypicker -> true/false`. I tried doing with a callback function but it goes into an Inf. Loop as denoted in the comments.

Comment: When does the infinite loop occur? What interaction do you have to do to trigger it? Or does it happen immediately on mount?

Comment: I added a CodeSandboxIO snippet.